# How to Share Image from API(URL) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here I want to `share` `image` which I get through `API`. I tried different method for this functionality but I did not get any solution because every solutions have for only one image.

Exactly, I get multiple image from `Url` and I open any particular `image` in next page. So, I want to `share` that `image` which I opened in another page.

I tried for `sharing image` but I could not did this. Whenever I try to `share` that `image`, `Image` `url` `share` with `sharing` option on `device` but I want `share` `image` not `URl` of `image` How I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to download the image like this:

```
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
```

then create an image on the device using the downloaded image like this ([Read and Write Files](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)):

```
final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final path = directory.path;
final file = File('$path/image.png');
file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
```

The getTemporaryDirectory() is in the plugin [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider). Now, you have the image you'd like to share stored in the temporarily as "image.png" and you can use the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example) plugin to share the image like this:

```
Share.shareFiles(['$path/image.png']);
```

Answer (score 2):

**modified code with package update for image from network(API)**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;

void shareImage({required String url}) async {

      final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
      final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      File file = await File('${directory.path}/Image.png')
          .writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

      await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(file.path)], text: 'Share');}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @abdulrazak, At first, you have to download the image in a temporary path & then you can share the image as you want. used Dio to download the image & share_plus for sharing

```
void _shareNetworkImage(String url) async {

    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = '${tempDir.path}/test.jpeg';

    await Dio().download(url, path);
    
    Share.shareFiles([path]);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [esys_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share) plugin.

1. Install it, and then get dependencies:

   ```
   dependencies:
     esys_flutter_share: ^1.0.2
   ```
2. Import the plugin to your code:

   ```
   import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
   ```
3. Use the below code:

   ```
   var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://yourImageURL.jpg'));
   var response = await request.close();
   Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
   await Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg');
   ```

Comment: As of the date, the package wasn't really maintained by anyone since 2019. No recommended. Got some issues which wasn't fixed or merged.